# nginx: why multiple conf files?

Tags: nginx

There are multiple nginx conf files on single installation. Here is what I found:

1. /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
2. /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
3. /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
4. more in /etc/nginx/conf.d
5. more in /etc/nginx/sites-available

What's the use of those multiple conf files? What is going to happen if there are conflict? Which one is the master copy?

Comment: Secondary conf files doesnt replace the main one. They extend it providing a context for other sysadmins to infer what is each one for.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Start with `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, all of the other files are `included` into it. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) for details.

Use `nginx -T` to see the complete configuration as `nginx` sees it.

Comment: I can't believe so few people found this useful....maybe its a sign of hope...that people are reading documentation carefully now, at least other people are :)

Comment: Maybe it's a sign that the answer lacks in details. And as such, is not that useful.