# Nginx default.conf missing on centOS 7

Tags: php, nginx, centos7, nginx-config

I recently install `Nginx` on my server lab, after seeing several videos Nginx And The LEMP Stack I saw the teacher navigate to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` and vi the `default.conf`. 
I try on my server lab but i can't find the `default.conf` at `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, the folder was empty but the server is running and i can access the public ip from my internet browser

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916769/nginx-why-multiple-conf-files/42924272#42924272)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am likely using the newest `Nginx`, which has been updated since this course came out and is different on `CentOS 7`. I need to edit `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` for the current server configuration on CentOS v7.

and for see the complete configuration as nginx use this command line `nginx -T`

Comment: This "answer" leaves more questions than answers